# Firebase Flutter Web Github Action

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I want to deploy Flutter Web to my firebase hosting, so far i have no issue, however when i introduce a package that requires token it wont work and throws error on step "- uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0"

Let's say my project name is example_web and the package that requires github token is example_package

My Flutter example_web/pubspec.yaml

```
#the third party package that requires the token
example_package:
 git:
   url: https://github.com/example/example.git
   ref: main
```

Where the example_package requires github personal access token

and my github action is
firebase-hosting-merge.yml (note this works perfectly if im not using the example_package in my project and the app is successfully deployed to firebase hosting)

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - release
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.16.5'
          channel: 'stable'
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EXAMPLE_WEBSITE }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: example-web-project-id
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_EXPERIMENTS: webframeworks
```

Now i introduced a secret into the example_web repository and put the personal access token and named it EXAMPLE_PACKAGE_TOKEN

Now, what part do i need to adjust in my firebase-hosting-merge.yml or pubspec.yaml if any.

I tried adjusting

pubspec.yaml

```
example_package:
    git:
      url: https://{EXAMPLE_PACKAGE_TOKEN}@github.com/example/example.git
      ref: main
```

and the firebase-hosting-merge.yml
I added this part after the actions/checkout@v3

```
#rest of the code
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Replace placeholder with actual value
        run: |
          sed -i "s|{EXAMPLE_PACKAGE_TOKEN}|${{ secrets.EXAMPLE_PACKAGE_TOKEN}}|g" pubspec.yaml
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
#rest of the code
```

But didn't work